# Is OAuth 2 the way to go for securing a simple web application without social login?

Tags: java, security, oauth-2.0, session-state

I've been recently trying to implement authentication for a new application but I run into a rabbit hole while doing it that left me with many questions.

I know that at the moment the buzz words around this are OAuth 2 or JWT and we started the implementation that way. But I don't get what the benefit is, if any, when your application is a private one that doesn't use any social login and which will never share their users' accounts with any other application to allow any type of SSO. For what I know, for this application is much easier implementing a typical authentication mechanism that relies in cookie sessions. Am I right in assuming this? How do Facebook or Twitter keep their users logged in in their native web apps? As far as I can tell, Facebook uses cookies.

A problem I know I may have in the future is if there would be a mobile application as cookies don't work nicely with those. In that situation, is using a token based approach the solution to the problem? Could I simply replace the sessionId with a token and use an Authentication: Bearer type that is verified with every request the same way the session is? I know JWT would simplify this by adding the information directly in the token so there is no need for any lookup in the server side. But I've read a way to invalidate these tokens is to keep a blacklist to run them against in case the was a breach in security or simply because the user has been removed. Wouldn't this actually make the implementation similar to the lookup the server does when using a session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using some standard sso solutions like oauth 2, saml2 etc you can make your application ready for accepting other login providers than your "login database"

This can be useful in cases where your customers dont want more then one login and they have oath2/saml2 infrastructure (like Azure Active directory).

How you decides to "remember that the client is authenticated" can be done in different ways, but the best would be to use what is standard for the platform you are developing on.